# a-1 Tag not needed, can it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In the question [Tennessee, a-1 zone - can i rent out on Airbnb?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61714/tennessee-a-1-zone-can-i-rent-out-on-airbnb) a new tag, [a-1](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-1),was created. In that question "a-1", was a zoning designation for agricultural land. But in other contexts it might have a quite different meaning. Even where it is a  zoning designation, it may not mean the same thing in different municipalities, let alone different states.

I don't think this tag is helpful. Can it be deleted?

Comment: The tag is not used on any questions, so it will be deleted automatically in (very soon timeframe).

Comment: @Nij it **was** used on the linked question at the time I posted the above.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the tag. As you said, it's both useless and potentially ambiguous.

Tags can't be manually removed, even by mods, but a tag that is unused will be purged from the system automatially.